# Document type "externalapp" - what is it?

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

Trying to download docs from the Google Docs using Java client library and getting some documents with type "externalapp".

What is this type and what is the proper way to handle such kind of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those can be shortcuts created by third-party applications that integrate with Google Drive using the Drive SDK but store their data in a different storage system: https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview

Comment: Any idea how can I create such a shortcut ?